# webserver | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist

Tags: docker

I am setting up PHP, NGINX, and MYSQL with Docker on a windows machine for the first time. After running `docker-compose up` command, I am getting an error in command prompt as below:

> webserver  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist

Structure:

- Dockerfile
- Dockerfile_Nginix
- docker-compose up
- config
  ---nginx
  ----app.conf

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apk update && apk add \
    build-base \
    vim

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S www && \
    adduser -u 1000 -S www -G www

USER www

COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

EXPOSE 9000
```

**Dockerfile_Nginix
**

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./config/nginx/app.conf /etc/ngin/conf.d/app.conf

COPY . /var/www
```

**app.conf**

```
server {

    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www;
    location ~ \.php$ {

        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: sandboxapp
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www

  webserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_Nginix
    image: nginx
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./config/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    depends_on:
      - app
```

````
Ran the `docker-compose up` command

    ```
    C:\Projects\Php\sandbox>docker-compose up
    [+] Running 2/0
     - Container app        Created                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
     - Container webserver  Created                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
    Attaching to app, webserver
    app        | [18-Mar-2023 18:26:00] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
    app        | [18-Mar-2023 18:26:00] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
    app        | [18-Mar-2023 18:26:00] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
    app        | [18-Mar-2023 18:26:00] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
    app        | [18-Mar-2023 18:26:00] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
    app        | [18-Mar-2023 18:26:00] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
    webserver  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
    webserver  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
    webserver  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
    webserver  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
    webserver  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
    webserver  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
    webserver  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:26:01 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:26:01 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.23.3
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:26:01 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:26:01 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:26:01 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:26:01 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:26:01 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 20
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:26:01 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 21
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:26:01 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 22
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:26:01 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 23
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:26:01 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 24
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:26:01 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 25
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:26:01 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 26
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:26:01 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 27
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:49:08 [error] 20#20: *1 directory index of "/var/www/" is forbidden, client: 172.23.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.216:8080"
    webserver  | 172.23.0.1 - - [18/Mar/2023:18:49:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 153 "-" "AVG Antivirus"
    webserver  | 172.23.0.1 - - [18/Mar/2023:18:49:14 +0000] "GET /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "AVG Antivirus"
    webserver  | 2023/03/18 18:49:14 [error] 21#21: *2 open() "/var/www404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.23.0.1, server: , request: "GET /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.216"
    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW9jC.png)


I reviewed the code, but could not find a bug in my code. I was not expecting any error message to display when I run the `docker-compose up` command. However, docker containers are running just fine.
````

Comment: It looks like your Nginx image `Dockerfile` tries to `COPY` in one additional configuration file, but then the Compose setup has a `volumes:` block that hides everything in the image, including the files you inherit from the base image.  Does removing that `volumes:` help at all?

Comment: I have removed the volume from Dockerfile_Nginix file. I was able to run the containers without the volume and this time I did not get the error mentioned above. I am new to this. What is the volume doing in the docker file?